# How can you archive RDS postgres database by using recovery.conf?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

1. Where can I locate and edit the file for an Amazon RDS instance?What is the path?
2. I have connected to the database using my command line. 
   Can I access this file via a ec2 instance (since I cannot connect to rds directly)?
3. Can you edit recovery.conf property values using any database queries?
4. What property should I change in this file?
5. Can I somehow use Amazon DB parameter for this?
6. How can this file trigger a script?
7. Can this script be executed periodically to archive the database?
8. How can we use the following pg_settings property to add one more script while archiving the database?

   "archive_command";"/etc/rds/dbbin/pgscripts/rds_wal_archive %p"

Too many questions, but not much idea how to go about it and cannot find good documentation on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to all these are "you can't".

RDS is a sealed system. You don't get access to WAL archiving, except via the features RDS its self exposes in the form of read-replicas, backup management, etc. Internally RDS archives WAL to S3, but you don't have and cannot get access to the S3 buckets it uses. Nor can you change the `archive_command` or the script it invokes.

You can't make replication-mode connections to stream WAL, use logical replication, etc either. If you want more control and flexibility, don't use RDS. With control and flexibility comes more complexity and the need for more knowledge - be sure to read the manual!

Comment: Not in RDS. It's a sealed system. It's *designed* so you can't do that.